# Getting a document object instead of opening a page?

Tags: xpages

I have a view panel.   In my column's click event I have the following code:

```
var unid = rowData.getUniversalID();
var doc:NotesDocument = database.getDocumentByUNID(unid);
getComponent("inputTextContractorName").setValue(doc.getItemValueString("Form"));
getComponent("inputTextContractorSiteSuperName").setValue(unid);
```

The var property of my viewPanel's data property is set to rowData.

I have the UNID being displayed in the view.  The UNID listed in the view does not seem to match what is being returned in the code.  In fact I made a list of all of my documents and their UNID and none seem to match what is returned.

The Form value is blank so I am guessing I am not returning a document at all.

Any idea what I am doing wrong?

Comment: which version are you using? There was a problem with bad ClientId in LN prior to 8.5.3 http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21503624 Would this describe the issue you are seeing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried to reproduce the issue, but was not able to. Here is the code, I used. viewColumn5 displays the FORM item value for each document, calculated from rowData.getUniversalID()

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xp:view xmlns:xp="http://www.ibm.com/xsp/core">

    <xp:inputText id="inputTextContractorName"></xp:inputText>
    <xp:br></xp:br>
    <xp:inputText id="inputTextContractorSiteSuperName"></xp:inputText>
    <xp:br></xp:br>
    <xp:viewPanel rows="30" id="viewPanel1" var="rowData">

        <xp:this.data>
            <xp:dominoView var="view1" viewName="AllContacts" />
        </xp:this.data>

        <xp:viewColumn columnName="LastName" id="viewColumn3">
            <xp:viewColumnHeader value="Last Name" id="viewColumnHeader3" />

            <xp:eventHandler event="onclick" submit="true"
                refreshMode="complete">
                <xp:this.action><![CDATA[#{javascript:var unid = rowData.getUniversalID();
var doc:NotesDocument = database.getDocumentByUNID(unid);
getComponent("inputTextContractorName").setValue(doc.getItemValueString("Form"));
getComponent("inputTextContractorSiteSuperName").setValue(unid);}]]></xp:this.action>
            </xp:eventHandler></xp:viewColumn>
        <xp:viewColumn id="viewColumn4"
            value="#{javascript:rowData.getUniversalID()}">
            <xp:this.facets>
                <xp:viewColumnHeader xp:key="header" id="viewColumnHeader4" />

            </xp:this.facets>
        </xp:viewColumn>
        <xp:viewColumn id="viewColumn5">
            <xp:this.facets>
                <xp:viewColumnHeader xp:key="header" id="viewColumnHeader5" />

            </xp:this.facets>
            <xp:this.value><![CDATA[#{javascript:var unid = rowData.getUniversalID();
var doc:NotesDocument = database.getDocumentByUNID(unid);
doc.getItemValueString("Form");}]]></xp:this.value>
        </xp:viewColumn>
    </xp:viewPanel>
</xp:view>Column>
        </xp:viewPanel>
    </xp:view>
```

Comment: Thanks.  I as setting the var property of the panel's document property and not the direct var property of the view panel.